# How to call a custom single function from app.js using webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, webpack

i am trying to call a function inside html file, but i cant do that as the function has been defined inside the app.js file exported by webpack.js

here is the code snippet online.

[Webpack link](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ks-MzCToNYw9LF-wxlF)

i always do get the call to undefined function error.

I have searched related to it, but its unclear to me, how to call a single function from that file.

Comment: Define things that you want in the global scope as `window.thing = valueofthing` within `app.js`

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. i figured that out, as soon as i posted the question :)